# How to stop CMake from passing platform specific flags to compiler?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, cross-platform

I'm trying to cross-compile my application. I created a CMake file that builds my application with Emscripten which works as expected. Now I'm modifying the CMake file to compile my application with MinGW. The problem is that CMake is passing MacOS flags that Windows g++ doesn't recognize.

CMake is passing these options to g++ (as well as a path to an object file and a source file)

```
-I/usr/local/include  -O3 -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13   -std=gnu++1z
```

Then I get this error from g++

```
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmacosx-version-min=10.13’
```

Is there an easy way that I can stop CMake from passing MacOS specific options to a Windows compiler? Or a way for g++ to ignore these unrecognized options?

---

I'm currently compiling with `find` and `xargs`. This is just a temporary solution because I really want to get this working!

---

I’ve been googling around for a while and I can’t seem to find a solution for this. I tried using `make` but it seems to have trouble with spaces. My final option is a bash script. I’d rather not use bash as a build system!

---

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file. The Emscripten build works (with `EMBUILD` defined) but the `MinGW` build doesn't. I tried setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to all sorts of crazy values but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Classic_Tower_Defence)

option(EMBUILD "Build with emscripten, mingw otherwise" YES)

set(EMSCRIPTEN_CC /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.37.37/libexec/emcc)
set(MINGW_CC /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
if(EMBUILD)
    set(CC ${EMSCRIPTEN_CC})
else()
    set(CC ${MINGW_CC})
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
    set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING YES)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CC})
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CC})
set(RES_PATH /Users/indikernick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Classic_Tower_Defence-dcezwdbogljnithjukklclgyblij/Build/Products/Debug/Classic\ Tower\ Defence.app/Contents/Resources)

#if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RELEASE)
    set(EXTRA_FLAGS "-O3 --closure 1")
#else()
#    set(EXTRA_FLAGS "-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1")
#endif()

if (EMBUILD)

set(LINKER_FLAGS " \
  ${EXTRA_FLAGS} \
  -s WASM=1 \
  -s USE_WEBGL2=1 \
  -s USE_SDL=2 \
  -s TOTAL_MEMORY=805306368 \
  -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 \
  --pre-js '${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Webpage/init.js' \
  --shell-file '${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Webpage/index.html' \
  --preload-file '${RES_PATH}@/' \
")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " \
  ${EXTRA_FLAGS} \
  -msse3 \
")

else()

# -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L./ -Wl,-rpath,./ -lopengl32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2_Mixer -lglew32 -o main.exe

set(LINKER_FLAGS " \
  -static-libstdc++ \
  -static-libgcc \
  -L../lib \
  -Wl,-rpath,./ \
  -lopengl32 \
  -lSDL2 \
  -lSDL2_Mixer \
  -lglew32 \
")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -DGLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT")

endif()

include_directories(/usr/local/include/)

set(SOURCE_FILES 
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/create spawner.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit death system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/game info model.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/game info view.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/splash damage system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower beam rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/aura damage system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load map.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/cursor systems.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower reset rof system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/base damage system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit death sound system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit motion system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/count live units.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower beam anim system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load towers.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/turret damage system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower sound system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load prototype.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/stats controller.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit death anim system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower aura rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower aim system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit damage system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/slow effect system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/game logic.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/next wave.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit regen system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit effect system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/poison effect system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load waves.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower projectile rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit health rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit walk anim system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/init map info.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load level.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/sound queue.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/unit death rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower rof system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/stats view.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/spawner timing system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load base.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/stats model.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/spawner system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/preview entity.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/game view.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/create tower.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/ui view.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/get wave info.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/firing anim system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/create level.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/tower range rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/load spawner.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/map rendering system.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/Game/app.cpp"
        "Classic Tower Defence/main.cpp"
)

add_executable(Classic_Tower_Defence ${SOURCE_FILES})
if (EMBUILD)
    set_target_properties(Classic_Tower_Defence PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME index.html)
else()
    set_target_properties(Classic_Tower_Defence PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME main.exe)
endif()
set_target_properties(Classic_Tower_Defence PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

You can probably tell that I'm not a CMake expert! I should be using generator expressions and find modules. I really don't know how to deal with strings and making sure that there are backslashes and quotes in the right places. But it works (half of it does)

Comment: Did you try `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)`?

Comment: **Cross-compilation** means that you build you application on one machine (*host*) for being used on other machine (*target*). What *host* and *target* in your case are? Host - Windows, target - MacOS? Also, for cross-compiling you need **cross-compiler**, suitable for pair host-target. Then, for cross-compiling using CMake you need appropriate **toolchain** file. Do you have all of these?

Comment: I'm compiling a Windows (target) application on MacOS (host). I have the MinGW toolchain that compiles Windows executables on MacOS. I have Wine for running the windows executables. A few months ago, I created a simple "hello window" application with SDL2 and MinGW

Comment: I'm getting really close to resolving all of the linker errors I'm getting. I'll try `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` after I get it working manually.

Comment: I got my application working without CMake so I know what options I need to pass to the compiler and linker. @Florian I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: @Kerndog73 If you could please add your CMake code to the question? Otherwise it's difficult to tell why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I've successfully tried [the following minimal example](https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world) - assuming from the visible paths in your code that you did install [mingw](/questions/tagged/mingw) via e.g. `brew install mingw-w64`:

**Edit**: Same procedure also successfully tested with [this OpenGL example](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world.git
Cloning into 'cmake-hello-world'...
remote: Counting objects: 56, done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 56
Unpacking objects: 100% (56/56), done.

$ cd cmake-hello-world/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build

$ export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
$ export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ 

$ cmake -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/5.0.3_3/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /.../cmake-hello-world/build

$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target Hello
[ 25%] Building CXX object Hello/CMakeFiles/Hello.dir/Speaker.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libHello.a
[ 50%] Built target Hello
Scanning dependencies of target CMakeHelloWorld
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CMakeHelloWorld.dir/HelloWorld.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable CMakeHelloWorld.exe
[100%] Built target CMakeHelloWorld
```

The main thing is that compilers and system/platform variables have to be defined before the `project()` command. And [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) is the key to enable [cross compiling](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-toolchain).

As @Tsyvarev has commented this is normally done in a [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) file (to not "pollute" your cross-platform CMake code).

Your complete code is better suited to be reviewed on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.